# Bash expand / preview expansion of curly braces

Tags: bash

In bash is there a way to preview (and/or expand) curly braces when used in arguments (I'd prefer preview but if that's not possible, then expanding would be okay)?  I know you can do it with filenames and wildcards by pressing ESC + ?, but what if it's not actual files and simply arguments that you want expanded or to preview the expansion of?

For example, if `touch {a,b}{1,2}` is entered at the prompt, is there some way to preview that that will expand out to `a1 a2 b1 b2` (in whatever order it would expand out to).

Answer (score 3):

Simple: Use `echo`.

```
$ echo touch {a,b}{1,2}
touch a1 a2 b1 b2
```

Comment: +1 for a creative solution.  I can't help but wonder if there's a native way though.